# MS Access Select the most recent date for each unique Id

Tags: ms-access, datetime

I am working with MS Access Database.
I have following table:

```
Product Id      Date Of Purchase
    A              01-01-2008
    B              01-01-2013
    C              01-01-2012
    A              01-01-2014
    B              01-01-2007
    C              01-01-2011
```

I need to find records for the latest bought products (for all Products)

i.e Desired Output should be:

```
Product Id      Date Of Purchase
    A              01-01-2014
    B              01-01-2013
    C              01-01-2012
```

I am relatively new to databases. Please help me with the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Max](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/min-max-functions-HP001032255.aspx) function whilst [grouping](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/group-by-clause-HA001231482.aspx) by `Product Id`

```
SELECT Product ID, MAX(Date Of Purchase)
FROM [table]
GROUP BY Product ID
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Also want to know if I have another column like ProductName.. How can I fetch that also.. When I try to include it it says error. Error: You tried to execute a query which doesnt have MAX function on ProductName.

Comment: When grouping any colums within the select must be part of the Group by clause or within an aggregate function such as `Max`. I'm assuming `Product name` is unique per `Product Id` therefore you could do `SELECT Product ID, MAX(Product name), MAX(Date Of Purchase)` or alternativley you could add it to the group by clause `GROUP BY Product ID, Product name`